# Django admin form, thows error while set ArrayReference field, Djongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I'm newbie in Django, I got an error when trying to set ReferenceField to Record
This is models:

```py
from djongo import models


class Record(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    attatched_file = models.FileField()
    file_type = models.TextField()

class Diary(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.TextField()
    records = models.ArrayReferenceField(to="api.Record", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

[image: Here form]

Can someone tell whats am I doing wrong?